# How do I turn off or control the type of AURA LED light display from ASUS motherboard in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, asus

I have a system where the chasis fans are daisy-chained. Their LED wiring are also daisy-chained and connected to the ASUS x299-A II motherboard addressible RGB LED connector that is a 3-pin type. This ADD GEN2_2 connector is suppose to work with RGB WS2812B LED strips or WS2812B based LED strips.

I would like a way to turn off or control the type of AURA light display of these LEDs in Ubuntu 20.04 or via programming. Is there a way to do this? How can I do this?